# GoogleMaps says OpenGL version is < 2 for Emulator with GPU support

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es, android-emulator

I am using an Android 4.2.2 emulator with the "use host GPU" option enabled.
I am trying to get the Google Maps API to work in an application, but I keep getting this error message in my Log Cat:

```
Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
```

The Google Map fragment appears on the emulator, but it is just a gray square with two zoom buttons.

I know that there is evidently a bug in the emulator that does not report the OpenGL version correctly, but this seems to have been reported some time back in 2012, so I was hoping that would be fixed by now (I am using the Android 4.2.2 emulator version 17.2).

I was really exited that I can now allegedly use the google maps API in the emulator at version 4.2.1, but I just can't get the thing to work because of the OpenGL problem.

OpenGL is definitely enabled on the emulator as the OpenGL API Demos work fine.

Has anyone got this working on a 4.2.2 emulator?

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you using, what GPU and which driver (driver, not OpenGL) version is installed. Did you install the drivers from the GPU vendor's website, or do you use the drivers shipping with the OS?

Comment: I am using Linux (Fedora18) with the open source Gallium drivers: (OpenGL vendor string: X.Org, OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620, OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.1). Like I say, the opengl ApiDemos work fine....